# Saving Bitmap to PNG file changes Pixel data

Tags: android, bitmap, png, steganography

I'm trying to modify the LSB in Pixels in order to Store Information in a Picture. The Encoding and Decoding does work how ever when i store the Bitmap to a png file which should be lossless and reload it the Pixel values have changed. This ofcourse leads to wrong values when i put the character back to gether however most of the times this can be fixed by substracting 136 from the Byte before making a char out of it. The Problem has to be the storing and reloading as when i pass the Bitmap directly to the Decoder everything works fine.

Comment: We cannot see what you do with getMessage(). And also we cannot see how bytemessage is constructed.

Comment: added the method for creating bytemessage 
getMessage retrieves the chars out of the bytepictre Array which represents all RGB values 
How ever all this above is working when the Bitmap is passed directly to the Encoder 
The error has to occur when saving or reloading the bitmap

Comment: Possibly Gamma correction is changing your raw RGB colors.

Comment: Sorry but i still do no not see what you do with the result of getMessag(). And i cannot see what parameter charmessge of charstobyte() contains. And we cannot see how you use the result of charstobyte(). Please show complete consistent code.

Comment: If you think that BitmapFactory saving a bitmap to a png file and converting back to bitmap delivers a different bitmap then do this cycle also before you manupilate that bitmap.  Did you examine if when you do the cycle five times every reloaded bitmap is different from the former?

Comment: `bytepicture[i] =  (byte) ((byte) bytepicture[i] & 0xfe | bytemessage[i]);`. Well after that you have a manupilated byte array. But what are you doing with it? Are you making a Bitmap out of it? Again: show complete code so we can test it.

Comment: complete code posted just so you understand my Problem 
when i decode from the Picture i get total nonsense as the Byte values before i cast them into char are too big by 136 for some magical reason when this is corrected by substracting 136 i still get some strange Outputs 8 turns to 0 9 turns to 1 and "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" turns to "abcdef`abcdefgqprstuvwpqr"

Comment: Your code compiles but my test statements give always an empty result. getmessagelength() returns 0. `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files[0].getAbsolutePath());  
   String message = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   String password = "Chawoot";
   StegoEncoder stegoEncoder = new StegoEncoder(bitmap, message, password);
   Bitmap bitmap2 = stegoEncoder.createsteganogramm() ; 
   StegoDecoder stegoDecoder = new StegoDecoder ( bitmap2);
   String decoded = stegoDecoder.decodepicture();
   // decoded == ""`.

Comment: you have to remove the b-=136 as this was just a try to fix the coruption of the png which doesnt realy accomplish it. But i think i might have found the source of evil but i have to investigate that today. It seems like that PNG in Android is premultiplying the Alpha channel which ofcourse corrupts the RGB values.

Comment: Ok. At the moment i can only confirm your findings. Also a cyle to png and back before -as described in a comment of mine- does not help. It is strange that the 'h' is something special. Haha. Test with: ` String message = "habcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`.

Comment: Think that you are better off when you manupilate a png file/bytearray directly. There are several png librarys for android i saw. Good luck. Of course i'm interested if you find a solution for the alpha channel problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with giving quality value when you store image.

```
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,0, imageOut)
```

Second parameter is quality value which is between 0 to 100.

Comment: the second Parameter doesnt have any effects. Hint to the compressor, 0-100. 0 meaning compress for small size, 100 meaning compress for max quality. Some formats, like PNG which is lossless, will ignore the quality setting